# В чем отличие метода connect, принимающего const QMetaMethod &, от метода принимающего PointerToMemberFunction

Tags: c++, qt

В чем отличие метода:

```
QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *sender, const 
QMetaMethod &signal, const QObject *receiver, const QMetaMethod &method, 
Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection)
```

от метода

```
QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *sender, 
PointerToMemberFunction signal, const QObject *receiver, 
PointerToMemberFunction method, Qt::ConnectionType type = 
Qt::AutoConnection)
```

ведь они принимают в качестве сигнала и слота указатель на функцию-член?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба варианта делают одну и ту же работу - "связывают" методы друг с другом.

В первом варианте нет необходимости прописывать аргументы функций и использовать макросы `SIGNAL(...)`, `SLOT(...)`, что часто удобнее, но имеется проблема, если у вас сигнал, или слот являются перегруженными функциями, то придется прописать приведение к нужному виду, которое выиглядит страшновато (хотя, о чем это я, это же `С++`), в таком случае можно использовать второй вариант.

В целом первый вариант прописывается быстрее и выглядит понятнее, лаконичнее - минимум лишних слов, максимум нужной информации.

Естественно имеются внутрение отличия в реализации и обработке moc-компилятором, но при применении это не имеет значения.

Также обратите внимание на первый комментарий к моему ответу (от `Bearded Beaver`) - очень важное дополнение про которое я забыл сказать. А именно, если при соединении друх методов присутствуют ошибки, то, если у вас второй вариант (с макросами) то вы об этих ошибках получите сообщения во время компиляции и вывод ошибок будет во вкладку ошибок (`QtCreator`),  как обычно.

А вот об ошибках при коннекте в первом случае вы узнаете во время выполнения, при этом сообщения об ошибках будут выведены в консоль.

Так что если у вас коннект через `QMetaMethod` и сигналы не проходят - проверьте консоль

Comment: добавлю, что в первом случае проверка синтаксиса происходит в рантайме, из-за чего ошибку в можно банально пропустить. второй вариант найдет ее при компиляции

Comment: Пожалуйста, употребляйте [внутристрочное форматирование правильно](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/). Отредактировал вашу [правку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/328153) через принять-и-править, в следующий раз в подобных ошибках буду вынужден выбирать отклонить-и-править или отклонить.